# Freemarker - How to put variables in hashmap?

Tags: freemarker

I searched the web to find how to add some entries into an existing hashmap.

Consider this code:

```
<#assign foo={'bar':'go'}>
```

I want to add a new entry and have something like this:

```
foo={'bar':'go','new':'entry}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Using concatenation:

```
<#assign foo=foo+{'new':'entry'}>
```

print the hashmap:

```
<#list foo?keys as k>
    ${k}: ${foo[k]} <br>
</#list>
```

The result is exactly what you want:

```
bar: go
new: entry
```

D.

Comment: so you ask the question and answer it straight away? whats the point of asking then?

Comment: `<#assign foo += {'new':'entry'}>` is a bit shorter (requires FreeMarker 2.3.23).